# hide attribute with null value using leaflet

Tags: leaflet, fields-attributes

http://jsbin.com/hinekaj/edit?html,output

this is a link to a map am working on. It will be great if someone could help me to hide the attributes that have "null" as their value. I am aware that I need to use the IF command but have been struggling with it.

```
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
          layer.bindPopup('<strong>Address: </strong>'+ feature.properties.address 
                          + '<p></p>Sample 1: '+ feature.properties.sample_1 + ' Pb'
                          + "<p></p>Sample 1: "+ feature.properties.sample_1 + ' Pb'
                        + " , Sample 2: "+ feature.properties.sample_2 + ' Pb'
                         + "<p></p>Sample 3: "+ feature.properties.sample_3 + ' Pb'
                         + " , Sample 4: "+ feature.properties.sample_4 + ' Pb'
                         + '<p></p>Sample 5: '+ feature.properties.sample_5 + ' Pb'
                         + ' , Sample 6: '+ feature.properties.sample_6 + ' Pb'
                         + '<p></p>Sample 7: '+ feature.properties.sample_7 + ' Pb'
                         + ' , Sample 8: '+ feature.properties.sample_8 + ' Pb'
                         + '<p></p>Sample 9: '+ feature.properties.sample_9 + ' Pb'
                         + ' , Sample 10: '+ feature.properties.sample_10 + ' Pb'
                         + '<p></p>Sample 11: '+ feature.properties.sample_11 + ' Pb'
                         + ' , Sample 12: '+ feature.properties.sample_12 + ' Pb'
                         + '<p></p>Sample 13: '+ feature.properties.sample_13 + ' Pb'
                         + ' , Sample 14: '+ feature.properties.sample_14 + ' Pb'

         ); 
        },
```

Comment: If you need help with code, please include a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck within your question body.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38590864/how-not-to-display-a-text-in-popup-when-its-not-filled-in-leaflet/38592668#38592668

Answer (score 1):

This is a programming question rather than a GIS question, but anyway:

There are several approaches to the problem. This uses a simple loop and a lookup table for the property labels:

```
var propertyLabels = {
    address: '<strong>Address</strong>',
    sample_1: 'Sample 1',
    sample_2: 'Sample 2',
    sample_3: 'Sample 3',
    sample_4: 'Sample 4',
    sample_5: 'Sample 5',
    sample_6: 'Sample 6',
    sample_7: 'Sample 7',
    sample_8: 'Sample 8',
    sample_9: 'Sample 9',
    sample_10: 'Sample 10',
    sample_11: 'Sample 11',
    sample_12: 'Sample 12',
    sample_13: 'Sample 13',
    sample_14: 'Sample 14'
}

onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

    var text = '';

    for (var property in feature.properties) {
        var value = feature.properties[value];
        if (value !== null) {
            text += '<p>' + propertyLabels[property] + ': ' + value + '</p>';
        }
    }
    layer.bindPopup(text);
}
```

Also note that the `if (value !== null)` check works only if the value received by JavaScript is actually [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) - even if your RDBS contains NULL values, they might be converted to something else along the way, depending on the protocols used.

Answer (score 1):

you could add this little test inside ( condition ? expr1 : expr2)

```
onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup('<strong>Address: </strong>'+ feature.properties.address 
                      + (feature.properties.sample_1 ? '<p></p>Sample 1: '+ feature.properties.sample_1 + ' Pb' : '')
     ); 
    },
```

Comment: Please note that `condition ? expr1 : expr2` is called the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)