# Hide null value attributes in Leaflet popup

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html

I have marker properties which are fetched from the database and displayed as a table. I want to hide the "reply" feature property when it's null and display it only when there is a text entry against it.

Similarity: [hide attribute with null value using leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206864/hide-attribute-with-null-value-using-leaflet)

Although it is a similar question but I am not sure how to get the property labels as shown in the answer.

My code:

```
    function returnQuery(feature, latlng) {  
        return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(
            "<table>" +
            "<tbody>" +
            "<tr>" + "<th>" + "Query ID: " + "</th>" + "<td>" + feature.properties.id + "</td>" + "</tr>" +
            "<tr>" + "<th>" + "Issue Placement Date: " + "</th>" + "<td>" + feature.properties.q_date + "</td>" + "</tr>" +
            "<tr>" + "<th>" + "From: " + "</th>" + "<td>" + feature.properties.q_name + "</td>" + "</tr>" +
            "<tr>" + "<th>" + "Query/Problem Statement: " + "</th>" + "<td>" + feature.properties.query + "</td>" + "</tr>" +
            "<tr>" + "<th>" + "Reply: " + "</th>" + "<td>" + feature.properties.reply + "</td>" + "</tr>" +
            "</tbody>" +
            "</table>");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initiate an empty string, fill it if there is a `feature.properties.reply` entry and append it to your `return` statement.

```
function returnQuery(feature, latlng) {
  let reply_string = ""
  if(feature.properties.reply) { // null is falsy
    reply_string = "<tr>" + "<th>" + "Reply: " + "</th>" + "<td>" + feature.properties.reply + "</td>" + "</tr>"
  }
  return L.marker(latlng).bindPopup(
    "<table>" +
      "<tbody>" +
        "<tr>" + "<th>" + "Query ID: " + "</th>" + "<td>" + feature.properties.id + "</td>" + "</tr>" +
        "<tr>" + "<th>" + "Issue Placement Date: " + "</th>" + "<td>" + feature.properties.q_date + "</td>" + "</tr>" +
        "<tr>" + "<th>" + "From: " + "</th>" + "<td>" + feature.properties.q_name + "</td>" + "</tr>" +
        "<tr>" + "<th>" + "Query/Problem Statement: " + "</th>" + "<td>" + feature.properties.query + "</td>" + "</tr>" +
        reply_string +
      "</tbody>" +
    "</table>"
  );
}
```